# How to convert time to seconds with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to be able to store for example 2:30pm in a column in SQLite, and be able to pull that time and convert it to seconds, does SQLite have a function for this?

I was reading http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and they do state they have a time function, but can I do this? I know that SQLite does not have a time datatype, but what type should I store it as then, varchar?

```
2:30pm --> 52200
```

---

I was reading more into this: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

and it seems like the list of time acceptable is :

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

So does that mean you can't use 2:30pm as a format?

Comment: What are you going to use the data for? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: I am creating a database for an iPhone Buss stop App, where I want to store the time in 2:30pm format, but when I pull the info, it would be useful for it to be in seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you will need the value to be in seconds from the beginning of the day (per your clarification) you can just store as an integer. To convert it to seconds from the beginning of the day rather than 1970 simply subtract midnight of the current day from it.

Something like this
    strftime('%s','2004-01-01 14:30:00') - strftime('%s','2004-01-01 00:00:00')

If 2:30pm that you are trying to store is current time then you can shorten it to
    strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s','2004-01-01 00:00:00')

Comment: When you stay store as an integer, do you mean storing "2:30pm" as an integer? Will that work?

Comment: it seems like you are using 14:30 (24 hour format) and I have 2:30pm (12 hour format).... How do I get 2:30pm to be 14:30? I also have many times in this table, 9:40am, 10:50am, 1:40pm, and so on.

Comment: Yes, that part you will need to do outside of the database. You could simplify the task by adding 12 hours iff 'pm' was found at the end. But you will have to put that logic outside of the SQL.

Comment: I changed my table to 24 hour format and this worked perfectly: `SELECT strftime('%s','2004-01-01 ' || stop_time) - strftime('%s','2004-01-01 00:00:00') FROM route_stop_list `

Comment: This also works fine too: `SELECT strftime('%s','1970-01-01 ' || stop_time) FROM route_stop_list`